# GCM Android demo error when connecting to device

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-networking

I am trying to learn about GCM and a newbie at this...I am running the demo at: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html. However, I can get my device(HTC S) registered because of the following error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 8080): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

In my Activity I am getting this message : `From GCM: device successfully registered!`

And then getting these messages: Trying (attempt %1$d/%2$d) to register device on Demo Server

These are the parameters for my application:

```
static final String SERVER_URL ="http://localhost:8080/Server_Demo";

static final String SENDER_ID = "902733651294";
```

I have a hunch that this has to do with how my network is defined on my computer and/or my device...
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Picture of web server thru a "Dynamic web project" using Eclipse.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The demo server is not running on your phone's localhost (i. e. the phone itself), that's for sure. Is it running anywhere? First deploy the demo server, then change SERVER_URL accordingly.

In general, GCM assumes that you have some cloud infrastructure (i. e. a hosted Web server somewhere). That's what C stands for.

Comment: thanks! I deployed my server project named "Server_Demo"  before running the application on the device. The SERVER_URL is "http://localhost:8080/Server_Demo"

Comment: Where did you deploy it (on what device)? I don't think the demo server is an Android app. From the phone's standpoint, "localhost" stands for "the phone itself".

Comment: I deployed using Eclipse by creating a Dynamic web Project" as per the tutorial.I have a diffrent application that I deployed on the device. However, it is not registering for some reason...Thanks for your help!(I added an image of my web project)

Comment: Your computer is NOT localhost from the phone standpoint. The registration is failing because the phone cannot reach the server URL, which is not pointing at you computer, as your computer is not localhost.